# How can I express "and/or"?

Tags: words

When stating two things e.g. `A` and `B` , and not counting the possibility of "neither", there exists `A`, `B` and `A and B`. To express all of them at once, "and/or" is commonly used. What are the ways to express this in Japanese? I came up with `両方またはどちらか一方` but I feel it's a little bit unwieldy. Is there a shorter or better way to express this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way is to say `A,Bの少なくとも一方`, `AとBの少なくとも一方` "at least either out of A and B".